# Test class for Rest

Tags: unit-test, apexrest

**Rest class :**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/uhb/sdefs/')

global with sharing class GSSRestResourceChatter{

    @HttpPatch
    global static String doPost(){
        List<ChatterDTO> fieldParsers = (List<ChatterDTO>)JSON.deserialize(
            RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring(), 
            List<ChatterDTO>.class);    

        System.debug('REST Context>>>>>>>>>>>'+RestContext.request.requestBody.tostring());
        System.debug('fieldParsers>>>>>>>>>>>'+fieldParsers);


     // do something   


    }

    global class ChatterDTO{
        public String ParentId{ get; set; }
        public String Body { get; set; }

    }  
}
```

**Test class:**

```
@isTest 
private class Test_GSSRestResourceChatter {
static testmethod void testGSSRestResourceChatter(){

 Account a = new Account(Name='Tester', 
        AccountNumber='101552',
        Account_Group__c = 'Sold To Party'
        );
        insert a;

System.debug('accountid>>>>>' +a.Id);
   Test.startTest();  

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        String jsonm ='[{"Some String"}]';
        req.requestURI = 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/uhb/sdefs/'; 
        req.httpMethod = 'POST';
        req.requestBody = Blob.valueof(jsonm);
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;    
        GSSRestResourceChatter.doPost(); 
        GSSRestResourceChatter.ChatterDTO thisChatter = GSSRestResourceChatter.doPost();
       // System.assert(thisChatter!=null);
      System.assertEquals(thisChatter.ParentId, String.valueOf(a.Id));


     Test.stopTest();

}
}
```

I am getting error while saving the test class as

> Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to
>   GSSRestResourceChatter.ChatterDTO at line 23 column 43

Please help me to sort out the error

Comment: What is actually returning the doPost() method? A string containing some sort of JSON serialization of a ChatterDTO object? If not you can assign ChatterDTO with a Object.valueOf of a String value

Comment: doPost() method returns String .  Yes serialization has been done for ChatterDTO object @Enreeco

Comment: Now on line 23 use "GSSRestResourceChatter.ChatterDTO thisChatter  = (GSSRestResourceChatter.ChatterDTO)JSON.deserialize(GSSRestResourceChatter.doPost()); ... this should work!

Comment: JSON.deserialize is done in doPost method.

Comment: The doPost() method returns a String and not a ChatterDTO object

Comment: Yes it returns getAsString not ChatterDTO object @Enreeco

Comment: You need to provide the actual implementation of the method to be of more help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33679/discussion-between-dominic-edward-and-enreeco).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fact that the doPost() method is not returning a ChatterDTO object